# Issue when trying to delete parent element of an image

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a book project in JavaScript using a grid container to house the "cards" that are created whenever a button is clicked. On each card there is a clickable button which should delete that entire card only when clicked. However, regardless of what card I click the image on, it always deletes the last created card in the grid.

I tried giving the clickable image an onclick attribute with a value of "this.parentNode.parentNode.remove()". This deletes a card like I want it to, except it always deletes the last card in the grid container no matter which card I want to specifically delete. I can't figure out how to only delete the direct parent card of the image that was clicked.

Code Below:

```
let content = document.getElementById('contentContainer');


let books = document.querySelector('.books');


let addBook = document.getElementById('addBook');


let submit = document.querySelector('button');


let bookTitle = document.getElementById('title');
let bookAuthor = document.getElementById('author');
let bookStatus = document.getElementById('status');


let myLibrary = [];


let newCardContainer;

let removeCard;


let cardColor;

function Book(title, author, currentStatus, present) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.currentStatus = currentStatus;
    this.present = present
}


Book.prototype.createCard = function () {
    let newCard = document.createElement('div');
    let textContainer = document.createElement('div');
    let titleText = document.createElement('p');
    let authorText = document.createElement('p');
    let imgContainer = document.createElement('div');
    let btnContainer = document.createElement('div');
    let btnRead = document.createElement('button');
    let btnNotRead = document.createElement('button');
    if (cardColor == true) {
        newCard.style.borderColor = "green";
    } else if (cardColor == false) {
        newCard.style.borderColor = "red";
    }
    removeCard = document.createElement('img');
    newCard.className = "book";
    newCard.id = "newCard";
    textContainer.className = "textContainer";
    imgContainer.className = "imgContainer";
    removeCard.setAttribute("src", "imgs/book-remove-outline.svg")
    removeCard.setAttribute("onclick", "this.parentNode.parentNode.remove()");
    removeCard.id = "removeCard";
    btnContainer.className = "btnContainer";
    btnRead.className = "btnRead";
    btnRead.setAttribute("onclick", "read();");
    btnNotRead.className = "btnNotRead";
    books.appendChild(newCard);
    newCard.appendChild(textContainer);
    newCard.appendChild(btnContainer);
    btnContainer.appendChild(btnRead);
    btnContainer.appendChild(btnNotRead);
    textContainer.appendChild(titleText);
    textContainer.appendChild(authorText);
    newCard.appendChild(imgContainer);
    imgContainer.appendChild(removeCard);
    titleText.textContent = title.value;
    authorText.textContent = `by: ${author.value}`;
    btnRead.textContent = "Read";
    btnNotRead.textContent = "Not Read";
}


function addBookToLibrary() {
    let newBook = new Book(bookTitle.value, bookAuthor.value, bookStatus.value);
    if (newBook.currentStatus == "read") {
        cardColor = true;
    } else if (newBook.currentStatus == "not read") {
        cardColor = false;
    }
    myLibrary.push(newBook);
}


function changeDisplay() {
    if (content.style.display = "none") {
        content.style.display = "flex";
    } else if (content.style.display = "flex") {
        content.style.display = "none";
    }
}


addBook.addEventListener('click', function() {
    changeDisplay();
});

submit.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    let counter = 0;
    if (bookTitle.value == '' || bookAuthor.value == '') {
    
    } else {
        event.preventDefault()
        addBookToLibrary();
        myLibrary[counter].createCard();
        counter++;
    }
});
```

Comment: Please include the rest of your code so that people can actually run your full solution and see the problem.  If you can format it as a [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do), even better.  I also want to point out that the `id` attribute needs to be unique within a document (eg, there can only be a single element with an id of "removeCard"); I don't know that this is the underlying issue, but it's something you should know either way.

Comment: When you ask a question you should make a minimally replicable product whenever possible. You can do a stack snippet or provide a link to a code pen where you have replicated the issue.